# Can't federate AWS Appsync if there is a custom type `AWSDateTime`

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, apollo-federation

I am trying to use Apollo Federation to connect subgraph from AWS Appsync. When I start federation I got this error: `UNKNOWN: Unknown type AWSDateTime`. It seems Federation doesn't recognise AWS Scalar type `AWSDateTime`. Is there a way to extend Apollo federation to support Appsync types?

The graphql schema I have on Appsync includes:

```
type Order {
  ...
  timestamp: AWSDateTime!
}
```

I am using `rover` to compose the subgraph:

```
rover supergraph compose --config ./supergraph.yaml
```

The error I got is:

```
error[E029]: Encountered 1 build error while trying to build a supergraph.

Caused by:
    UNKNOWN: [test] Unknown type AWSDateTime
```